# Why doesn't my Bootstrap 3 row fill the parent width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 to make a grid-based template for a modal (which I'm also using Bootstrap for). The modal appears, and all the content is there ... but the styling is off. It looks like the `row` classes don't fill their parent containers, even though there's no styling that should make that happen. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ytLo.jpg) - you can see that neither the row in the header nor the row in the body take the width of their parent. I've tried poking around other SO posts for information, but I can't seem to find anything on why a row wouldn't fill its parent width.

#### Update:

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62JKb/). It looks like it actually works on JSFiddle ... which means it's not a problem with the immediate template, so I'm looking into other possible causes. Thanks for the tip, calvin!

#### HTML

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header ht-modal-header">
            <h1>
                <a href="#">Bombay Teen Challenge</a>
            </h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <address>
                        1 Chium Village, Ambedkar Road<br/>
                        Bandra West<br/>
                        Mumbai 400052
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <abbr>e: </abbr> kkdevaraj@bombayteenchallenge.org<br/>
                    <abbr>p: </abbr> +91 22 2604 2242
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ht-modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="types">
                        <span class="prevention-label"></span> Prevention, Education, Teen
                    </div>
                    <div class="facebook">
                        <span class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></span> BombayTeenChallenge
                    </div>
                    <div class="twitter">
                        <span class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></span> @BombayTC
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="people">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label>People: </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                Dr. Rama R. Rao<br/>
                                Monte Hackney
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="partners">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <label>Partners: </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                None Available
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### LESS

```
.prevention-label {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4ECDC4;
}

.ht-modal-header {
  a {
    &:hover, &:focus {
      color: white;
    }
    color: white;
  }

  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(@ht-teal, darken(@ht-teal, 5%));
  background: -webkit-gradient(@ht-teal, darken(@ht-teal, 5%));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(@ht-teal, darken(@ht-teal, 5%));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(@ht-teal, darken(@ht-teal, 5%));
}
```

Comment: [Give us a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @calvin Thanks! I updated the post with a fiddle for you.

Comment: Just a small style tip: you only have to declare a column-size for the smallest screen device with same # of desired columns: so, for instance, "col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" can always be written as "col-lg-2 col-xs-6" with the same result (and less copy + paste)

Answer (score 4):

If you nest rows in columns you must understand that inside a `.col-lg-6 .row` the whole thing starts new (at 100%) and for you you to fill it have to use `.col-lg-12` inside of it.

This snippet should work for you

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="people">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>People: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                Dr. Rama R. Rao<br/>
                Monte Hackney
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partners">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label>Partners: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                None Available
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```